# What are 2 pros and 2 cons of using Roll20?

Tags: dnd-5e, tools, online-roleplaying, roll20

Considering the current health concerns we all face these days, I'm looking into virtual tabletop solutions. I've created a Roll20 account and am familiarizing myself with it. However, I'd like to get some input about the platform in general.

I realize this borders on opinion, so I'm only interested in answers from those that have actually used Roll20 more than just in passing.

**What are 2 pros and 2 cons of using Roll20?**

Comment: "General input" is a bit too broad I think and yes, as-is this would be opinion-based. What specific concerns do you have about using Roll20 instead of playing in-person? What specific problem have you come across with Roll20 that you're trying to solve? What criteria do we have to judge answers on? Currently this *is* essentially just asking for our opinions.

Comment: I don't have enough experience with the system to have had specific concerns, that's why I'm asking. If, for instance, a con of Roll20 was that no more than 4 players can use it at once - that's a significant issue I should know about when considering using it.

Comment: This is probably a better question for chat, as it seems too open-ended as-is for the Q&A.

Answer (score 3):

I've run several games for friends who live in other cities on Roll20 and the current campaign I run is there. There are more pros and cons than this but as you only asked for two, here they are:

**Pros:**

1. all the important features you need to play are free and if your DM does decide to pay, everyone in the game can see the paid features like tokens and modules.
2. It's relatively easy for everyone to jump onboard and play, and with a little prep, it can speed up things like player handouts and rolling as there are in app dice rolling mechanics (if you aren't superstitious like my players about them)

**Cons:**

1. In my experience, there is no method to show verticality. I.e you are going to have to remember how high flying enemies like dragons are.
2. Getting the in game grid to line up with maps you upload can be a little finicky at times. There is a tool which is supposed to help set the roll20 grid, but I tend to find that he grids still slowly drift due to the difficulty in getting the grid size exactly right.

My best advice is for the DM to get used to the system and try to set up as many features beforehand as possible. Spells can be set from the compendium which makes rolling easier and you can preset tokens to character sheets and set them with things like HP bars as well. I find running games on it works just as well as my in person ones, though sometimes things can get slowed by technical difficulties.

Comment: You captured my experiences almost to a T.

Comment: Glad to know it's not just me! The more prep time I take the smoother it runs, but it still has a few sticking points

Comment: Mine as well. Although my biggest issues were found on the character sheet I was using. If you don't lock them to the version you are using sometimes I lost data.